# CakePHP 3 events

Tags: events, cakephp-3.0

I want to create an entry in my Notifications table if a particular find method has return value on my Contacts table.

So in ContactsTable I create an event.

```
use Cake\Event\Event;

public function checkDuplicates()
{
    //... some code here
    $event = new Event('Model.Contacts.afterDuplicatesCheck', $this, [
            'duplicates' => $duplicates
        ]);
    $this->eventManager()->dispatch($event);
}
```

I have created ContactsListener.php at /src/Event

```
namespace App\Event;

use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Event\EventListenerInterface;
use Cake\Log\Log;

class ContactsListener implements EventListenerInterface
{

    public function implementedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'Model.Contacts.afterDuplicatesCheck' => 'createNotificationAfterCheckDuplicates',
        ];
    }

    public function createNotificationAfterCheckDuplicates(Event $event, array $duplicates)
    {
        Log::debug('Here I am');
    }
}
```

In my NotificationsTable.php I have the following code.

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->table('notifications');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $listener = new ContactsListener();
    $this->eventManager()->on($listener);
}
```

I guess this part is the problem, as I never get the log entries. The cookbook is not enough clear about this and all code what I found was not the same what the cookbook describes, even for cake 3.

How and where should I attach the listener?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are working with two separate local event manager instances, they will never hear from each other. You either have to explicitly subscribe to the manager on your `ContactsTable` instance, or use the global event manager that gets notified about all events:

> [...]
>
> Each model has a separate event manager, while the View and Controller share one. This allows model events to be self contained, and allow components or controllers to act upon events created in the view if necessary.
>
> #### Global Event Manager
>
> In addition to instance level event managers, CakePHP provides a global event manager that allows you to listen to any event fired in an application.
>
> [...]

**[Cookbook > Events System > Accessing Event Managers](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html#accessing-event-managers)**

So, either do something like

```
\Cake\ORM\TableRegistry::get('Contacts')->eventManager()->on($listener);
```

which will only work until the registry is being cleared, or subscribe globally

```
\Cake\Event\EventManager::instance()->on($listener);
```

#### On a side note

In order for this to work at all, your `NotificationsTable` class must be instantiated somewhere. So, I'd suggest to wrap this up in a utitlity class, or maybe a component, which will listen to the event instead, and use the `NotificationsTable` to save notifications.